# Find two positive real numbers, whose difference is 100 and whose product is a minimum

Tags: calculus, optimization

First off, this is a single-variable calculus optimization problem. At first glance, the problem seemed extremely trivial, however the solution to it seems to be deceptively tricky (at least to me at this moment in time).

> **Problem:** Find two positive numbers whose difference is $100$ and whose product is a minimum

---

**My Attempted Solution :**

Let's assume, $a, b \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $b < a$

First we set up an equation for the difference of $a, b$, I've used absolute values to restrict $a,b$ to values $\geq 0$
$$|a| - |b| = 100$$
$$\implies |a| = 100 + |b|$$

Next we set up an equation for the product of $a, b$

$$(|a|)(|b|) = b^2 +  100|b| \ \ \ \ $$

Defining a function $f$, to minimize to product of $a , b$ :

$$f(b) = b^2 + 100|b|$$
$$\implies 
    f'(b) = \begin{cases}
2b +100, \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ b \geq 0 \ \ \ \ (1)\\
2b - 100, \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ b < 0 \  \ \ \ (2)\\
\end{cases}  $$

Solving for $f'(b) =0$, with case $(1)$, yields $b = -50$, an immediate contradiction. Solving for $f'(b) =0$, with case $(2)$, gives $b=50$, $a=150$. Although that is a valid solution (*EDIT: As correctly pointed out in an answer below, this is also a contradiction*), they are not the minimum values.

The correct values, just thinking about it should be, $a = 100$, $b = 0$. However, trying to minimize it, using the equations I set up, don't yield the correct solution. **Why is that so?**. I don't seem to have made any mistakes as far as I can tell

Comment: There is no minimum, we can make the product arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: Intuitively a = 0, b = 100, unless you say a that a,b  >  0, nonetheless ab is arbitrarily close to 0.

Comment: Simply put the minimum exists outside the acceptable range (x = -50) so no solution exists.  By forcing the positivity and putting in the absolute values (which was unnecessary) your created a function that in not differentiable at 0.  f'(x) = 2x + 100 for x > 0 and f'(x) = 2x - 100 for x < 0 but f'(x) is undefined at x = 0.  Neither of those are solvable so this mehtod of finding local minimums simply won't work because because they are out of range.

Comment: 50, -50 is the minimum if you remove the constraint that a and b are positive.  When you add in the constraint, there is no local minimum (or maximum) within the interval.  So we look at the behavior at the endpoints.

Comment: Um ... " I've used absolute values to restrict a,b to values ≥0"  Actually that does the *exact* opposite.  It allows |a| and |b| to be positive while a and b *can* be negative.  So you have inadvertently set up an equation to find the maximum of the negative of the the product.  (At b = 50 a = 150 the negative of their product is at a maximum).

Comment: To restrict to positive you simply do $b - a = 100$ and $0 < a < b$.  Solve for the min and you get a = -50 b=50.  As that's unacceptable find minimum of $a > 0; b > 100$.  As that's impossible the answer is impossible.

Comment: As $b > 0$ your derivative (2) is not at all valid ever and needs to be tossed out entirely you have $f'(b) = 2b + 100; b > 0$.  Period.  That's it.

Comment: Aside: $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ restricts $a$ and $b$ to be positive (or maybe nonnegative, depending on your meaning). $|a|$ is just redundant, since $|a| = a$.

Comment: You would make life much easier for yourself by asserting 0 < a < b, and not using the absolute values .  Also, {100, 0} is not a solution because 0 is not positive.

Comment: Note that the precise meaning of _positive_ (does one allow $0$ or not) is vital to whether this question has a solution or not. Though the most common (though not in France) interpretation is to exclude $0$, I would suggest writing explicitly ${}>0$ (or ${}\geq0$ if that was meant) for clarity.

Comment: To clarify why you got the 50,150 answer whcih isn't right: "with case (2), gives b=50" - this is also a contradiction because case 2 is if b < 0. So your logic in taking b = 50 is wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the minimum of a function lies on the *boundary* of the region of parameters, then simple differentiation will not work.  You must also check the boundaries, which in this case includes the (true) solution $(0,100)$.

A trivial illustration:  Find the minimum value of $f(x) = x$ for $x \ge 0$.  Differentiation is of no help in finding the solution at $x = 0$.

Comment: But 0 isn't positive?

Comment: True. Under that condition, there is no minimal solution, because as ε → 0, ε(100-ε) → 0.

Answer (score 12):

Without loss of generality assume $b > a$ so $a + 100 = b$.

The product is $ab = a(a+100) = a^2 + 100a$.

To find an extrema we must solve for $f(x) = x^2 + 100x$ $f'(x) = 0$.

That is $2x + 100 = 0$ so $x = -50$ is the only extremum.

To see what type of extremum it is we must evaluate $f''(x)$ is at $x = -50$.  $f''(x) = 2$ so $f''(50) = 2 > 0$.  $x = 50$ it *is* a minimum.

So $b = 50$ and $a = -50$ is the minimum product. But those aren't positive.

We need to find the minimum positive product.  If $0 < x$ then $f'(x) > 2*0 + 100$ so the product is increasing.

So the minimum product occurs at $a = \min (0, \infty)$ and $b = \min (100, \infty)$.

But .... there are no such real numbers.

Which... isn't a problem.  You fell for the oldest trick in the book-- one which every mathematician I have ever known has fallen for once or twice--- that just because a problem might *ask* for something, that doesn't mean the thing exists.

Now had it be two non-negative real numbers the question would have been valid, but it wasn't and it isn't.

Answer (score 6):

The minimum does not exists. There exists a minimizing sequence:
$$
(a_n,b_n)=(1/n,100+1/n)
$$

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to find an optimum, you need first to verify that an optimum exists. In this instance, one does not: as $b$ gets closer and closer to $0$ from above, $b(100+b)$ gets closer and closer to $0$ from above.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question **Why is that so**, there *is* a mistake. Your case (1) yields an immediate contradiction, as you've noted, but so does your case (2). It yields $b=50$, which violates your assumption that $b<0$. So your equations do lead to the conclusion that the min cannot occur where $f'(b)=0$.